# Correct way of using react with electronjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, electron

I have external api hosted in the cloud and I would like to write desktop app for management. Last version of electronjs I worked with was version 8 and over that time a lot of changed especially from security perspective. The concept of preload was introduced and I would like to know is it fine to write renderer as react app with redux toolkit and make api calls that way or should I use preload script to get data on the server side.

I would like to know what is a proper way of writing such app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is totally fine to use react and redux toolkit in your renderer.
To quickly get started, you could use something like [electron react boilerplate](https://github.com/jschr/electron-react-redux-boilerplate) or one of the several other boilerplates available online.

I don't understand why you would want to use preload to fetch from the server.
You can treat the renderer as just another browser instance and make requests to the server directly from your react app using fetch or xhr.

Preload is generally used to run code before the renderer has loaded. I generally use it as a bypass to turning on `nodejsintegrations` for my electron apps, but you can read more about it in the [official docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload)